# I get a 404 error not found in CodeIgniter HMVC

Tags: codeigniter

I hope someone can help me with this error, I have these following lines of code in my project HMVC CodeIgniter 3.0

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://web.com/project/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

the root of my folders are as follows

```
project
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | modules
| | | login
| | | | models
| | | | | ...
| | | | views
| | | | | ...
| | | | controllers
| | | | | home.php
|.htaccess
```

result:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

I need help.. thanks!

Comment: What was the URL that gave you that error? Was it a CodeIgniter 404, or the browser default 404?

Comment: the CodeIgniter own , but if the controller shows me the "welcome" that comes by default

Comment: @Jean_Paul what is "CodeIgniter own"? Does the homepage work, but the other pages don't, because that would mean RewriteEngine has a problem, and since your `.htaccess` file looks good, I would check that it's enabled in you `php.ini`.

Comment: Error 404 is the same CodeIgniter , the ini.php already configured , is hosted on a website, but if I answered the driver that comes by default , others not :(

Comment: @Jean_Paul I'm having trouble understanding. Are you saying it is shared hosting? What driver do you mean? Was it the homepage "root" url or a subpage?

Comment: I worked correctly on my localhost , but when I went up to the server, I came out this error.

Comment: Do a `phpinfo()` call and check that rewrite is indeed enabled. Try a different codebase and see if it's the code or the server configuration.

Comment: if this included the module and still does not work

Comment: I don't understand. If what was included in what module? Did you do phpinfo? Did you try a different project proven to work to know if it was server configuration or code?

Comment: you will have a project in HMVC ? to try ?, Apparently all HMVC I try to upload, I get one mistake .. I get I can not use other models and I get the same error.

Comment: Your default_controller is login/home. Your structure is login/controller/home.php. It should be (your structure) login/home.php. Put home.php under your login folder..

Answer (score 2):

change your

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://web.com/project/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://web.com/project';
```

Comment: Typically this will be your base URL, WITH a trailing slash: in comment section\

Answer (score 0):

If you already using `.htaccess`, just remove `index.php` in `$config['index_page']` and most of my projects using codeigniter, i leave my `$config['base_url']` empty. Also to make sure, your `project` controller actually exist in controller folder and properly using CI format. Read the manual for more information.